# How can I delete a file if it starts with <html> in bash?

Tags: command-line, bash, rm

I need a bash command to delete the entire file if the file itself begins with `<html>`.

I'm not sure the best way to go about this...

Context:  I download a series of files via curl requests.  Most time the downloads and processing work fine.  But other times the download request results in a 404 for whatever reason.  When I get those, the contents of the downloaded file begins with a html tag.  When the rest of my processing hits this file, it hangs.  So I want to run a command prior to my other processing to cat each of the files and delete the file if it has this html tag.

Comment: You want to search for files beginning with `<html>` or delete a file that has `<html>` in its name?

Comment: Yes.  I added an additional comment

Comment: @Seth I don't want to edit a title when a mod has done so already, but the title seems wrong to me. Files are deleted the same way regardless what it starts with. The question is how to _identify_ files matching a certain condition, not how to delete them.

Comment: Do note that many HTML files have their start tag preceded by a `<!doctype something>`.

Comment: Is a python script acceptable? It is much easier to write and read than bash magic.

Comment: @Siy I think Python is acceptable, I am interested in seeing what you have :)

Comment: @Seth There are already many good answers. No reason to write another one in Python that is functionally equivalent.

Comment: @SiyuanRen We always like new good answers! We want to build a repository of information, not just answer the question for one person.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please, could you put some of your time to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 20):

To address the question that prompted you to ask this one, rather than the one you actually asked:

curl can tell you the status code in addition to downloading the file. You do not need to check the file's contents for that. An example of how to check the status is

```
status=$(curl -w '%{http_code}' "${url}" -o "${file}")
test "${status}" -eq 200 || rm -- "${file}"
```

The various options you can use with `-w` are documented in the manual, and depending on your needs, you may want to extend this to output more information and parse it, and/or change the check of the status code to allow more than merely 200.

Comment: It is important to quote the file, in case it contains spaces or special characters. Hence, instead of `$file`, use either `"$file"` or `"${file}"`. For safety, you should also quote the URL, as either `"$url"` or `"${url}"`.

Comment: @PaddyLandau That was because I had originally hard-coded the URL and file name, and changed it to variables just before posting my answer. Thanks, edited. Also, for safety, `rm` should have `--` before the file name. Some folks really do use files named `-i`.

Answer (score 12):

You could use this find command to delete all files only containing only the `<html>` pattern in the first line:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'sed q "$0" | grep -qP "^<html>$" && rm "$0"' {} \;
```

Comment: What's with the `\;`?

Comment: @Shahbaz `\;` is required to identify the end of the `-exec` action

Comment: This won't work (and, at least in theory, is dangerous) if any of the filenames contains double quotes. Using `-exec sh -c 'head -1 "$0" ...' {} \;` is more reliable.

Comment: @Dennis thanks a lot for the suggestion, I fixed the command.

Comment: I generally prefer find solutions, but in this case it seems a lot more confusing and convoluted than a simple for loop..

Answer (score 8):

I just tested this, it works.

Run `shopt` first [because we don't want to parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs):

```
shopt -s nullglob
```

then use a simple bash `for` loop to find files that begin with `<html>` and remove them:

```
for i in *; do if [ "$(head -n 1 "$i")" == '<html>' ]; then rm "$i"; fi; done
```

It would be safer to use:

```
for i in *; do if [ "$(head -n 1 "$i")" == '<html>' ]; then rm -i "$i"; fi; done
```

to have `rm` ask before removing any files, just in case.

Note that `shopt` isn't strictly needed but it prevents certain issues from occurring if the directory is empty or there happens to be a file with an asterisk in its name.

Comment: Perfect, thank you.   I think I should have been able to come up with that on my own.  Probably time for a break.

Answer (score 1):

Not every automating task should be done with shell. Here is a Python script instead

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os

def is_html_file(file_name):
    # Actually, try/except is better
    # But not very readable for someone not familiar with python
    if not os.path.isfile(file_name):
        return False
    with open(file_name, 'rb') as f:
        # A lot of HTML file starts with doctype
        # It is better to check that too
        return f.read(6) == '<html>'

def main():
    # Use os.walk if recursion is needed
    for fn in os.listdir('.'):
        if is_html_file(fn):
            print 'Removing', fn, '...'
            os.remove(fn)

main()
```

Maybe it is more verbose than the equivalent bash commands, but it is

1. More readable
2. More extensible
3. Never ever going to be screwed up by file names with spaces and shell metacharacters, however careless you are.